# Best/efficient way to split a Base64 String to same length chunks to transfer over http in Android

Tags: java, android, string

What is the best/efficient way to split a Base64 String to same length chunks to transfer over http in Android & what is the optimal chunk size?

Comment: Why do you need to split it into chunks at all?  The HTTP protocol doesn't require this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-to-equal-length-substrings-in-java) if your problem is related with splitting the String into equal length chunks with Java.

About the optimal chunk size, it depends on too many factors: what kind of network (wifi, 2g, 3g...), what are you trying to do with the data, what are your data reliability restrictions, or even the battery duration restrictions you could have... It is hard to answer that part of your question if you do not provide some extra information about it.