# splitting binary string into several two character?

Tags: java, substring

I have a binary string like `"100010"`. I want split it into several two character like -> `"10"`, `"00"`, `"10"`.

How can i do it? Unfortunately I have no idea about it.

```
String str = "100010";  
int counter=0,end=1;  

for (int h = 0; h < str.length(); h++) {
     String ss = str.substring(counter, end);
     System.out.print(ss);
     counter = counter + 2;
     end = end + 2;
}
```

Please help mee.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-to-equal-length-substrings-in-java  might help

Comment: What do you see when you step through your program in you debugger? Did you want to have space between the numbers?

Answer (score 3):

As you want to split the every 2 characters, you need to keep the difference between `counter` and `end` to be equal to `2`. The variable `h` is redundant and in fact will cause a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
String str = "100010"; 
int counter = 0;
int end = 2;

while (end <= str.length()) {

   String ss = str.substring(counter, end);
   System.out.println(ss);

   counter += 2;
   end += 2;
}
```

Alternatively, you could do a regex split for every 2 characters. This uses regex look-behind combined with `\G`, the zero-width assertion that matches the position where the previous match ended:

```
for (String s: "100010".split("(?<=\\G..)")) { System.out.println(s);  }
```

Both versions produce:

```
10
00
10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String[] StringSpliter(String OriginalString) {
    String newString = "";
    for (String s: OriginalString.split("(?<=\\G..)")) { 
        if(s.length()<3)
            newString += s +"/";
        else
            newString += StringSpliter(s) ;
    }
    return newString.split("/");
}
```