# Split a String into block of a specified length (expept the last)

Tags: java, string, split

Let's say I have the following string:

```
String = "0123456789abcdefg";
```

How can I split it in blocks of 5, so that I get an array of string like

```
["01234", "56789", "abcde", "fg"]
```

Notice the last string is 2 characters long.

Is there a simple way to do so in Java?

Comment: Come on show me your code first?

Comment: you can use String.length and String.substring

Comment: Honestly, that would result in a very trivial code, a for-loop and a couple of String.substring() try yourself a bit first...

Comment: Well, I don't have any code. I am asking this question hoping there was a function already provided in the language.

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-to-equal-length-substrings-in-java

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Thank you. I voted to close my question, as it is a duplicate of the one you linked.

Answer (score 3):

```
//UNTESTED CODE!!
String in = "0123456789abcdefg";
List<String> blocks = new ArrayList<String>();

int i = 0;
for ( ; i < (in.length()-5) ; i += 5) { //while there are more than 5 characters remaining 
    blocks.add(in.substring(i, (i+5) ); 
}

blocks.add(in.substring(i, in.length()) //add any remaining characters
```

Comment: +1 for the comments in your code (although I insist the OP should have tried first)

Comment: @morgano yeah I agree completely - I just felt like doing it. OP, this answer was a disservice to you. Next time you run into a problem like this, do everything you can to figure it out yourself - that's how you learn to program, because programming *is* figuring things like this out. Come to SO when what you've figured out isn't working.

Comment: interesting thing is that, doing micro-benchark between your solution and the one-liner answer in the duplicate question, yours runs at least 5 times faster... ha... just saying... makes sense as in the one-liner a regex must have to be internally compiled, so moral of the story is shorter code doesn't mean more efficient

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method should be enough for your purpose, something like:

```
final int CHUNK_SIZE = 5;
List<String> chunks = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i*CHUNK_SIZE < string.length() - 1; ++i)
  chunks.add(string.substring(i*chunkSize,Math.min((i+1)*chunkSize, string.length())));
```