# How to split a string into equal parts and store it in a string array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm fairly new to Java and am stuck on a particular homework question where a String gets passes and from there I have to split it into parts equal to an Integer that was passed.

For example: String "HelloWorld" is input and it has to be divided by 2 and those parts then have to be put into an array that has two parts like: array[hello, world].

Is there anyway to do this using a FOR loop?

My  code so far enters the whole String into each array element. Here is my code:

```
String[] splitIntoParts(String word, int size) {

    String[] array = new String[size];     

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = word;
        println(array[i]);;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: use sub string.does every word divide to 2 parts with same length?what should output if length is even?

Comment: Do you literally need 2 equal parts?

Comment: On what criteria , are you going to split the string?

Comment: @Renjith: according to the code, there should be n - 1 parts each of the size `size` and 1 part more of size `size` or less.

Comment: Another test that has to pass for this question is a String that is 15 chars long getting passed and I have to divide it into 3 equal strings and store them in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is my code:

```
    String[] array = new String[size];
    char[] charArray = new char[length(word)];
    char[] temp = new char[length(word) / size];
    int place = 0;

    // turn the string into an array of chars
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        charArray[i] = getChar(word, i);
    }

    // loop for each element of the desired string array
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        // fill a temp array with the correct characters and the corect amount of characters
        for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length / size; j++) {                
            temp[j] = charArray[place];
            ++place;
        }

        // insert the temp array into each element of the string array
        array[i] = new String(temp);
    }

    return array;
```

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways:

### Here's the regex version:

```
public void splitEqual(String s){
        int length = s.length();//Get string length
        int whereToSplit;//store where will split

            if(length%2==0) whereToSplit = length/2;//if length number is pair then it'll split equal
            else whereToSplit = (length+1)/2;//else the first value will have one char more than the other

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("(?<=\\G.{"+whereToSplit+"})")));//split the string

    }
```

`\G` is a zero-width assertion that matches the position where the previous match ended. If there was no previous match, it matches the beginning of the input, the same as `\A.` The enclosing lookbehind matches the position that's four characters along from the end of the last match.

Both lookbehind and \G are advanced regex features, not supported by all flavors. Furthermore, `\G` is not implemented consistently across the flavors that do support it. This trick will work (for example) in Java, Perl, .NET and JGSoft, but not in PHP (PCRE), Ruby 1.9+ or TextMate (both Oniguruma).

### Using Substring:

```
/**
     * Split String using substring, you'll have to tell where to split
     * @param src String to split
     * @param len where to split
     * @return 
     */
    public static String[] split(String src, int len) {
        String[] result = new String[(int)Math.ceil((double)src.length()/(double)len)];
        for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++)
            result[i] = src.substring(i*len, Math.min(src.length(), (i+1)*len));
        return result;
    }
```

You should also check this answer: [Google Guava split](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3760862/3809894)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, because it's concise, elegant, well documented and shows a proper function as requested in the OP (not like the rest of the answers being whatever); in other words: it is the best answer. one improvement though: integer ceiling is done fast with `ceil(a/b) = (a + b - 1)/b` (@Rohit already showed it too)

Answer (score 4):

First check if the length of the string is a multiple of the divisor:

```
if(str.length() % divisor == 0)
```

Then you know that you can grab equal chunks of it. So you use `substring` to pull them out,  in a loop.

```
while(str.length() > 0) {
     String nextChunk = str.substring(0,divisor);
     // store the chunk. 

    str = str.substring(divisor,str.length());
}
```

Will cycle through and grab a chunk that is `divisor` long each time.

Comment: Ur answer is reasonable

Comment: The string is always divisible by the number for my questions.

Comment: Does your answer store the chunks in an array?

Comment: @Nagash how about my answer?

Comment: @Nagash   Do you want to be stored in different arrays? or just one array which does not make sense

Comment: It has to be stored in one array for the tests to pass.

Comment: This is all you're getting out of me I'm afraid. Store them Into an array if you want them to pass the test

Answer (score 3):

Try the following application.It is dividing the provided word into equal parts based on the provided size per part

```
public class WordSpliter {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] words = new WordSpliter().splitter("abcdefghij", 4);
      for(String s : words) System.out.println(s);
  }

  private String[] splitter(String word, int size) {
      // Decide the size of the String array 
      int rest = word.length() % size;
      int arrSize = ((word.length() - rest) / size) + 1;

      // Declare the array and the start point of the word
      String[] words = new String[arrSize];
      int startPoint = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
          if (i + 1 == words.length) {
              words[i] = word.substring(startPoint, startPoint + rest);
          } else {
              words[i] = word.substring(startPoint, startPoint +  4);
              startPoint += 4;
          }
      }
      return words;
  }
```

}

Good Luck !!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Brute force

```
public static List<String> splitStringEqually(String text, int size) 
{
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>((text.length() + size - 1) / size);
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i += size) {
        result.add(text.substring(i, Math.min(text.length(), i + size)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "HelloWorld";
String firts_part=(String) s.subSequence(0, s.length() / 2);
String second_part=(String) s.subSequence((s.length() / 2)+1,s.length()-1 );
```

Try subSequence();

Answer (score 2):

Since length of a string is dived by 2

**Code**:

```
        String st ="HelloWorld";
        String firstPart = "";
        String secondPart = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < st.length(); j++) {
            if ( j < st.length() /2) {
                firstPart += st.charAt(j);
            }else
                secondPart += st.charAt(j);
       }

        System.out.println(firstPart);
        System.out.println(secondPart);
```

**Output**:

```
Hello
World
```

**Explanation**: you add to firstPart String as long as your index has not met the middle index of the String. When it passed the middle index of String, you make the secondPart

Comment: I'd rather not use += with String: it re-creates the `firstPart` as well as `secondPart` and could be (for large input) time consuming. 
Why don't you just put `firstPart = st.substring(bla-bla-bla); secondPart = st.substring(some-other-bla-bla-bla);`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thank you for your input, but the op ask for using the for loop

Comment: I need code that can work for varrying string lengths and divisions.

Comment: @Nagash  but you said it is dividable by 2? am I right? this works for that

Answer (score 2):

This is not plagarism, formatted the answer mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3761521 as per the question.

```
public static void main(String[] args){     
        String str = "HelloWorld";

        int parts = str.length()/3;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
                str.split("(?<=\\G.{"+parts+"})")
            ));

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at your input `HelloWorld`, You are trying to substring your input by Upper case letter.

You should go with that.

```
String str = "HelloWorldUser";
List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    String temp = (str.charAt(i) + "").toUpperCase();
    if (temp.equals(str.charAt(i) + "")) { // check for upper case letters
       indexList.add(i);
      }
 }
List<String> subStrings = new LinkedList<>(); // to keep the insertion order
for (int i = indexList.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) { // substring reverse order
     subStrings.add(str.substring(indexList.get(i)));
     str=str.substring(0,indexList.get(i));
 }
Collections.reverse(subStrings); // reverse to get original order
System.out.println(subStrings);
```

Out put:

```
[Hello, World, User]
```

If you want to get final result in to an array you can use

```
String[] arr= subStrings.toArray(new String[subStrings.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

A Simple solution is like

```
 static void split(String str, int n) {
    int partSize = str.length() / n;
    while (str.length() - partSize > 0) {
        String s = str.substring(0, partSize-1);
        System.out.print(s + " ");
        str = str.substring(partSize-1);
    }
    if (str.length() > 0) {
        System.out.print(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using regex as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitIntoParts("HelloWorld", 5)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitIntoParts("HelloWorld", 4)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitIntoParts("HelloWorld", 2)));
    }

    static String[] splitIntoParts(String word, int size) {
        return word.replaceAll("(.{" + size + "})", "$1\n").split("\n");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Hello, World]
[Hell, oWor, ld]
[He, ll, oW, or, ld]
```