# Not able to print very large strings in java (neither in Eclipse nor in cmd)

Tags: java, string, large-data

I am working with very large strings whose length range from 0 to 2*10^5.
When I try to print the strings on the console or using command line via `System.out.println`, nothing shows up. Only strings/substrings with 4096 characters show up. Also, I get no errors.

I also tried to print the characters one at a time using `System.out.print(chararray[i])` but to no avail.

I even tried tried to use the below but it did not work.

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();    
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(stringWriter);    
bufferedWriter.write(str);   //does not display       
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);    
System.out.println(sb);   //does not display
```

Displaying is important here since I am submitting my program on HackerRank and my program does not pass the test case due to this issue.

Can anyone please help?

Note: I know the strings are being stored properly since I was able to verify their lengths using `str.length();`

Comment: what about sb.toString() ?

Comment: Maybe this will fix it for eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912202/character-limit-for-system-out-println-in-java

Comment: I am using IntelliJ and able to print string length of 8192 using StringBuilder.

Comment: No, the eclipse setting doesn't work too. I had tried that earlier and even now. sb.toString not working too.

Comment: One thing thats pissed me off at least twice, sometimes Eclipse won't show a large string properly in the console, it's blank.  Copy that blank line (it's not really blank) and put in NotePad or NP++, paste it, see if it has data.  Twice now, eclipse was showing nothing but it was actually printing a value to the console - you just can't see it, WTF?

Answer (score 4):

> By default, Eclipse limits the amount of text in the console output
>   window. So if you are running a program which produces a lot of
>   output, the Console will only display the last n lines and you lose
>   the rest.
>
> Here is a tip which will allow you to have unlimited output in the
>   console:
>
> - Go to Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console
> - Uncheck "Limit Console Output" (Alternatively you can increase the Console buffer size.)

[Credits](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2008/05/increase-console-output-in-eclipse.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try dividing the string into multiple chunks and then write to a text file. 
You can refer below link to divide the string : [How to split a string into equal parts and store it in a string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114025/how-to-split-a-string-into-equal-parts-and-store-it-in-a-string-array)