# Reading textfile into arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files

How would you rad a textfile that is a bunch of seven letter words back to back into an ArrayList.
EX:  flowersflowersflowersflowersflowersflowers

I need to read them into the ArrayList as a single column.
EX:
Flowers
flowers
flowers
flowers

The words are not all the same, I just used flowers as an example, all of the words in the textfile are different.

A little little bit of additionally info, I dont know how many words are in the textfile I'm trying to read into the ArrayList.

Any help/example of code would be awesome!

Comment: Are they all 7-letters long and on the same line?  In that case, you should be able to use substring.

Comment: It's not impossible if they are all guaranteed to be 7 letters.

Comment: That's true ! @cding001 plz show us what you did so as we can help you !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string to equal length substrings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-to-equal-length-substrings-in-java)

Comment: they area all seven letters long!

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
File myFile = new File("data.txt");
BufferedReader readBuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));

ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

String line = null;
while ((line = readBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
    while (line.length() > 0) {
        myArrayList.add(line.substring(0,6);
        line = line.substring(7);
    }
}

readBuffer.close();
```