# How to delimit a string to a string with certain length with Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, char

I have a very long String. And I have a function write(String str) that can only support a string with 20 chars. How can I do to cut my long string into strings of 20 chars and loop in my write() function ?

Sorry, what I did :

```
for(String retval: pic.split("",20)) {
mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(characteristic, retval)
```

pic is my long String. however doing this, It's not doing what I want

Thank you in advance !

Comment: stack isnt free code-writing service... pls show attempts

Comment: For example: [Split string to equal length substrings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3760152)

Comment: Java String class in api is helpful . see split

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string to equal length substrings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-to-equal-length-substrings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, using arraylist of Strings, and using substring, supports more than 20 chars

```
String pic = "THIS IS A VERY LONG STRING MORE THAN 20 CHARS";

ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
int index = 0;

while (index < pic.length()) {
strings.add(pic.substring(index, Math.min(index + 20,pic.length())));
    index += 20; //split strings, add to arraylist
}

for(String s :strings){
    mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(characteristic, s); //write the string 
}
```

or, even better, using regex:

```
for(String s : pic.split("(?<=\\G.{20})"))
    mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(characteristic, s);
```

Comment: Isn't pic.length() instead of text.length() ? Thanks for this usefull answer tho

Comment: I didn't really verified the code but you are sure that this actually makes strings of 20 chars right ?

Comment: @Bob Yup, an array of 20length strings, which you iterate through and call the method.

Comment: Well Actually I got this error : java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length near index 12:
    (?<=\G.{20}) , do you know why ?

Comment: Yes! it finally worked using the first answer! Regex bugs for me. Anyway thanks for the help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**susbtring()**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm) method:

with this you can have the 20 first characters:

```
pic = pic.substring(0, 21)
```

Comment: The OP states that they want more than 20 chars :P that means you will have to loop

Comment: "that can only support a string with 20 chars".

Comment: He means that `mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic` can only support 20 chars, therefore, and I quote, needs "loop in my write() function"