# Android, String.split (String regex) doesn't split all the string

Tags: java, android, regex, split

I have a problem with String.split(String regex). I want to split my string in parts of 4 characters each.

```
String stringa = "1111110000000000"
String [] result = stringa.split("(?<=\\G....)")
```

When I print result I expect 1111,1100,0000,0000 but result is 1111,110000000000.
How can I resolve? Thanks.

Comment: This trick with `\G` in Java does not work in Android. See [Split string to equal length substrings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-to-equal-length-substrings-in-java) for alternatives.

Comment: Use the method `find` and the pattern `....`

Answer (score 2):

Here [a solution without regex](http://ideone.com/Xj0sKv) -

You begin at the string's end, extract 4 or less characters and prepend them to a List:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String stringa = "11111110000000000";
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int endIndex = stringa.length(); endIndex  >= 0; endIndex  -= 4) {
        int beginIndex = Math.max(0, endIndex - 4);
        String str = stringa.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
        result.add(0, str);
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Which results in the output:

```
[1, 1111, 1100, 0000, 0000]
```