# How to read a .txt file and split every 8 chars?

Tags: java, string, io

I have a text file that contains "binary", which is simply just a long string of binary numbers that will represent assembly instructions further down the road. At the moment what I want to do is take this long string of binary numbers and load it into a `String[]` 8 characters at a time.

So for example: 
`0000000100000002000000030000000400000005000000060000000700000008`

Would be read in as:

```
[0] 000000001
[1] 000000002
[2] 000000003
[3] 000000004
[4] 000000005
[5] 000000006
[6] 000000007
[7] 000000008
```

The only way I can think about doing this right now is by reading in the entire string and storing it in a `String` variable, then iterating through the variable 8 chars at a time and using `substring()` to slice the big string into smaller 8 char strings.

Surely there must be a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: *000000002* is not binary

Comment: They were examples, I know they aren't binary strings.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use regex provided by Alan Moore in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3761521/8116173) answer and if you prefer Java 8 solution, you might want to consider using `Stream`:

   ```
   String str = "0000000100000002000000030000000400000005000000060000000700000008";
   List<String> list = (Stream.of(str.split("(?<=\\G.{8})"))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())); // Result of splitting input String is stored in a List
   String[] strings = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]); // Create an array from contents of list
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings)); // print result array to console
   ```
2. If you are not allowed to use Java 8 features, you can use method `substring()` provided in `String` class:

   ```
   String str = "0000000100000002000000030000000400000005000000060000000700000008";
   ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); // To store results of cutting input String
   while(str.length() != 0) { // Until you reach end of String...
       list.add(str.substring(0, 8)); // Add first eight characters of input String
       str = str.substring(8, str.length()); // Cut input String to leave only characters not added to list in previous line
   }
   String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]); // Create a String[] and add contents of ArrayList to it
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // Print result String[]
   ```

Output you get in both cases:

```
[00000001, 00000002, 00000003, 00000004, 00000005, 00000006, 00000007, 00000008]
```

Comment: Elegant answer, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @user9253826 Glad that I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Scanner` and keep "scanning" the next 8 characters:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(...));
// you cannot use array here since you don't know how long the file is
// you can convert this array list to an array afterwards though.
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String eightChars;
while ((eightChars = s.findWithinHorizon(".{8}", 0)) == null) {
    list.add(eightChars);
}
```

`.{8}` is a regular expression that matches exactly 8 non-line-terminator characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a byte buffer of a 8 bytes so that each read can only take up to 8 characters. You can form a String from this buffer easily using the String constructor.

```
    char c[] = new char[8];
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File(""))) {
        while (reader.read(c) != -1) {
            strings.add(new String(c));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Handle exception
    }
```