# Modifying HashMap based on condition using streams java8

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I want to create a `HashMap<String,Integer>` from an existing `HashMap<String,Integer>` by applying some operations on the key of the Map.
Say suppose I have a String->

```
String sampleString= "SOSSQRSOP";`
```

then created a hashmap by taking only 3 characters from string like below(putting 0 as value):

```
Map<String, Integer> messages= new HashMap<>();
messages.put("SOS",0); 
messages.put("SQR",0);
messages.put("SOP",0);
```

The Actual task is to find total no of different characters from given string "SOS" with each key in the map and assign the no to value of each key.
Like below (End result):

```
Map<String, Integer> messages= new HashMap<>();
messages.put("SOS",0);
messages.put("SQR",2);
messages.put("SOP",1);
```

so I wrote code in java8 using stream given below:

```
    Map<String,Integer>  result= messages
            .entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e-> e.getKey(),
                    e-> e.getKey().stream()
                         .forEach(x-> {
                                if(!"SOS".equals(x)){
                                    char[] characters= {'S','O','S'};
                                    char[] message= x.toCharArray();
                                    for(int i=0; i< characters.length;i++){
                                        int index=0;
                                        if(characters[i] != message[i]){
                                            messages.put(e.getKey(),++index);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    ));
```

I am getting compile error. Can anybody help me write the code using stream.

Edited: Also please describe other approaches to do this. BTW creating first hashmap from given string was required in my case.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Why do you want to use streams? This is not what streams are for; they are used to transform items from a to b, not modify a.

Comment: @user7 I am getting Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<String,Integer>

Comment: @daniu I am transforming one hashMap(messages) to another HashMap(result) to get the desired result.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to premake the `HashMap`.  Stream collector `toMap` will make it for you:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

Map<String, Integer> result = Stream.of("SOS", "SQR", "SOP")
        .collect(toMap(
                s -> s,
                s -> (int) IntStream.range(0, 3)
                        .filter(i -> "SOS".charAt(i) != s.charAt(i))  // assume all words are 3-letters
                        .count()
         ));
```

However, if you already have the map and want to modify it, use `replaceAll`:

```
messages.replaceAll(
        (s, unused) -> (int) IntStream.range(0, 3)
                .filter(i -> "SOS".charAt(i) != s.charAt(i))
                .count()
);
```

If your task is to split the source message and compare each triplet against the first 3 chars, you can combine it all in one stream expression:

```
String message = "SOSSQRSOP";
int n = 3;

assert message.length() % n == 0;

Map<String, Integer> messages = IntStream.range(0, message.length() / n)
        .map(i -> i * n) // starting points of the n-grams
        .mapToObj(idx -> message.substring(idx, idx + n))
        .collect(toMap(
                group -> group,
                group -> (int) IntStream.range(0, n)
                        .filter(i -> message.charAt(i) != group.charAt(i))
                        .count()
        ));
```

Comment: Perhaps, replacing `3` with `"SOS".length()` would make it cleaner.

Comment: The first one is really nice. Also, one might assume that the distances are to be calculated from the first String that is found, which would make this `Stream.of(array)... .filter(i -> array[0].charAt(i) != s.charAt(i))`. What's the difference between `Stream.of(...)` and ´Arrays.stream(...)` anyway?

Comment: @Holger It also assumes that all other words are also at least 3 characters long.  I was just trying to keep out anything that does not directly pertain to the issue the OP is having to avoid drowning out the important parts

Comment: @daniu `Stream.of` is a *varargs*  method, hence, allows to write `Stream.of(element1, element2, ...)`

Comment: @daniu We don't know all the details of the task that OP is trying to solve.   Hopefully, this is enough to address his immediate issue and he can modify it as needed for his actual requirements

Comment: @Misha well, yes, the OP said that `"SOSSQRSOP"` has been split into three-character string, so that's given point. Now, the question is whether to treat `3` or `"SOS"` as starting point...

Comment: @Holger Here, based on the best guess of what OP is trying to do, I made it nice and clean

Comment: You could replace `.boxed()` with `.mapToObj(idx -> message.substring(idx, idx + n)`, that will not only avoid boxing to `Integer`, it allows simplifying *both*  `toMap` functions.

Comment: @Misha I like the way you implemented the count. As a suggestion, you could shorten the split by using `Pattern.compile("(?<=\\G.{" + n + "})").splitAsStream("SOSSQRSOP")` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-to-equal-length-substrings-in-java)).

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `forEach` in the value mapper, since it doesn't return a value.

```
String x = "SOS";
Map<String,Integer> result = messages
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e-> e.getKey(),
                                  e-> {
                                          int count = 0;
                                          for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++){
                                              if (e.getKey().charAt(i) != x.charAt(i)) {
                                                  count++;
                                              }
                                          }
                                          return count;
                                      }));
```

Comment: Where is x? i think this won't compile

Comment: may be x is the "SOS"

Comment: @Rcordoval my assumption is that x is the given String (whose value is "SOS" in the given example). It should be declared prior to the Stream pipeline.

Comment: Now I’d consider moving `e.getKey()` out of the loop but that’s a minor point. And `characters.length` → `x.length()`

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do IMO is not using `Stream`s at all, but `replaceAll`:

```
Map<String, Integer> messages = new HashMap<>();
// sample entries
messages.put("SOS", 0);
messages.put("SQR", 0);
messages.put("SOP", 0);

messages.replaceAll((k, v) -> {
    // calculate new value for each entry
    int diff = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < "SOS".length(); i++) {
        if ("SOS".charAt(i) != k.charAt(i)) {
            diff++;
        }
    }
    return diff;
});
System.out.println(messages);
```

Output

> {SQR=2, SOP=1, SOS=0}

Answer (score 1):

I assume, the input you have is a String containing all the characters. 
So you could skip the creation of the initial map and split the string into chunks of 3, mapping each resulting String to a key, and using some formula for calculating the diff for the value.

```
    String sampleString= "SOSSQRSOP";
    final char[] SOS = "SOS".toCharArray();
    Map<String, Integer> result = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, sampleString.length() / 3)
                                           .mapToObj(i -> sampleString.substring(3*i, Math.min(3*i+3, sampleString.length())))
                                           .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s,
                                                                     s -> (int) IntStream.range(0, s.length())
                                                                                         .filter(i -> SOS[i] != s.charAt(i))  
                                                                                         .count()));

    result.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
```

Regarding your own implementation:

```
for(int i=0; i< characters.length;i++){
   int index=0; //<-- this will always set the index to 0
   if(characters[i] != message[i]){
     messages.put(e.getKey(),++index); //<-- this sets the index to one before assigning it to the map entry value, resulting in being 1, always
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this: `e.getKey().stream()`, which means you are trying to stream over a single value, because your key is a String, and this is not possible.

You can do `e.getKey().chars().forEach(...);` and you will get the expected result or you can do something like `e.codePoints().forEach(...)`.

If you use one of the above methods you will also need to cast the entries to chars because `codePoints()` and `chars()` return IntStreams.

As @Holger mentioned in the comment, my first answer contained the following snippet `Stream.of(e.getKey().toCharArray())` which will give you a stream with a single `char[]`.

Definitely, there are better ways of doing what you want to do, but your question was about the compilation error.

Comment: `Stream.of(e.getKey().toCharArray())` would create a stream with a single `char[]` element.