# Regex for splitting a number ID (java)

Tags: java, regex

Hey everyone just wondering how I would go about splitting a number such as:

**"1100000000000001"**

to:

**"11.00.00.00.00.00.00.01"**

Possibly using regex?

Comment: Regex is for finding patterns within a string.  In this case, you're not looking for any pattern, you just want to put a dot every 2 characters.  This sounds like a great job for [`String#substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)).

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely try that out!

Comment: Also, an exact dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-to-equal-length-substrings-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split at every second char and join the elements of the resulting array using `.` as a delimeter:

```
String reg = "(?<=\\G..)";
String str = "1100000000000001";
String res = Pattern.compile(reg).splitAsStream(str).collect(Collectors.joining("."));
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: My answer is more or less like yours but since you've posted your answer a couple of minutes earlier than me, I have deleted mine .

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly!

Comment: @a.maz You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex is not the best solution for this problem. Constructing the string yourself offers a simple way to do this:

```java
String str = "1234567890";
String newStr = "";
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    newStr += str.charAt(i);
    if(i % 2 != 0 && i != str.length() - 1) {
        newStr += ".";
    }
}
System.out.println(newStr);
```

Comment: This solution works as well!

Answer (score 0):

using regex pattern :

```
String str = "1100000000000001";
String pattern = "(\\d\\d)(?!$)";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(pattern, "$1."));
```